# heroku pg:copy unknown command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

So, I've exceeded my DB table rows on heroku and have upgraded my DB to the standard postgresql DB which is unlimited. I've been following this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases

However, the command to copy the old DB data to the new DB isn't working, specifically it's saying:

```
 !    `pg:copy` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

This is the command I'm using as prescribed:

```
$heroku pg:copy DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE_URL --app sushi
```

HELP!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to update your heroku toolbelt - the old command is

```
heroku pgbackups:transfer DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL --app sushi
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mapping-pgbackups-commands

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!!! I had to un-install heroku, and install the new heroku toolbelt!

It's now working!